# Cannot decode Base64 buffer into opencv2 frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, base64

I aim to do inter process communication to transfer an opencv frame from a cpp process to a python process. To do that, I convert the frame into base64 and send it to a named pipe. When receiving the frame in the python code, I seem to be missing something about base64 decoding. I recreated my problem in these few lines:

```py
base_img = cv2.VideoCapture(0).read()[1]

im_b64 = base64.b64encode(base_img)

im_bytes = base64.b64decode(im_b64)
im_arr = np.frombuffer(im_bytes, dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.imshow('Window', im_arr) # wide blank rectangle
cv2.waitKey(2000)

img = cv2.imdecode(im_arr, flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

cv2.imshow('Window', img)
cv2.waitKey(2000)
```

im_arr seems like a valid array, therefore when displaying it with `imshow` it displays a weird blank vertical rectangle of like 200x5000.

Decoding this array using `imdecode` returns None. I have also already tried with the flag `IMREAD_ANYCOLOR`.

My code comes from https://jdhao.github.io/2020/03/17/base64_opencv_pil_image_conversion/#base64-to-opencv-image and seems pretty clear. Can someone spot what I am missing ?

Comment: since you never "imencode", you shouldn't "imdecode" either, so im_arr is what you want in this case.

Comment: Thank you @Miki , I didn't undestand the fact that np arrays were actually cv2 Mat by themselves.
Still, remains the fact that `imshow(base_img)` is valid and imshow of the base_img b64encoded, b64decoded and read from buffer is invalid (renders a wide white rectangle)

Comment: you should imshow `im_arr`, not `img`

Answer (score 0):

Things finally worked after encoding my image as jpg

````
image = cv2.VideoCapture(0).read()[1]
jpg_image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1]
jpg_b64_image = base64.b64encode(jpg_image)

buffer = base64.b64decode(jpg_b64_image)
jpg_image = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(jpg_image, flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

cv2.imshow('Window', image)
cv2.waitKey(3000)```
````